# javascriptのエラー内容が分かりません

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iphone, socket.io

client-ios.jsでエラーが起きているのですが、どこを直せばいいのかわかりません
`<` の記号でのエラーのようですけどどこにも使ってないのでさっぱりです
javascriptに詳しい方いらっしゃいましたらお願いいたします

エラー内容

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'　　　　client.js:1
```

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tomo-ono/20110530/1306740692
のサイトを参考に作成したのですが、解決方法が分かりません

上のURLを参考に作成したプロジェクトのソースコード

client.js

```
$(function() {
var socket = new io.Socket(null, {port: 8080});
socket.connect();

function iosHandleOrientation(event) {
    var orientData = event.accelerationIncludingGravity;
    socket.send(orientData.x + " " + orientData.y + " " + orientData.z );    
}

window.addEventListener("devicemotion", iosHandleOrientation, true);

socket.on('message', function(obj) {
    data = obj.split(" ");
    $('#data').append("<tr><td>" + parseFloat(data[0]).toFixed(3) + "</td><td>" + parseFloat(data[1]).toFixed(3) + "</td><td>" + parseFloat(data[2]).toFixed(3) + "</td></tr>");

});
});
```

server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http'),
    io = require('socket.io'),

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  fs.readFile('./socket.html','utf-8',doReard);
  function doReard(err,data){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
    res.end();
}
});
server.listen(8080);

var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('message', function(message) {
        client.broadcast(message);
        console.log(message);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('Conncection closed.');
    });
});
```

socket.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-   1.4.5.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="data">
<tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>z</th></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

ご指摘を受けましてserver.jsとsocket.htmlのコードを書き直したのですが以下のようなエラーが出ます

TypeError: server.use is not a function

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
  io = require('socket.io');
var server = express();

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

  server.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
  //fs.readFile('./socket.html','utf-8',doReard);
  function doReard(err,data){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
    res.end();
  }
});
 server.listen(8080);

var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('message', function(message) {
        client.broadcast(message);
        console.log(message);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('Conncection closed.');
    });
});
```

socket.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-  1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/images/client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="data">
<tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>z</th></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

何度も申し訳ありませんが詳しい方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 例えば一行目に`<script>`とか書いていませんか？

Comment: 今確認したところ特に＜script＞のようなコードは一行目以外にも見当たらないです

Comment: client-ios.jsを呼び出している<link>タグや<script>タグ前後に問題があることはないですか？

Comment: .jsファイル全体は<script>タグで囲む必要はないはずですが、囲んでいませんか？

Comment: client-ios.js を呼び出している記述が見つかりませんが、どのような仕組みで呼び出しているのでしょうか

Comment: client-ios.js の方のプロジェクトはほかのファイルが多く記述が長そうなので、とりあえず追記の方のプロジェクトを何とかしようと考えています

Comment: socket.htmlとclient.jsは同一ディレクトリに置かれていますか？

Comment: `https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-  1.4.5.js`  と途中に空白がありますが、これが余計ではないでしょうか。

Comment: すいません、それはここに貼るときに間違えたみたいで実際には空白はありません

Answer (score 4):

(この回答はもともと[重複先の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40263/20206)に投稿したものですが、重複としてクローズされたためこちらにも投稿しました)

---

`server.js`でリクエストのパスにかかわらず`socket.html`を返しているからではないでしょうか。

ブラウザは`<script src="client.js"></script>`というタグを見てサーバーに`/client.js`をリクエストしますが、返ってくるのはhtmlなのでそのようなエラーが出たのだと思います。

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) などを使うとルーティングが楽にできます。

関連リソース
[Express で静的ファイル（static ファイル）をホスティングする](https://maku77.github.io/nodejs/express/static-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

本家英語サイトに同様のエラーと、その解決方法がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926326/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got-what-does-that-mean

これに合致していませんか？

> You don't need the  tags when in an external .js file. Use these tags to embed a script inside HTML only.

と回答にあるので、日本語で言うと
「外部JSファイルにはタグは必要ありません。タグが必要なのはHTML内にスクリプトを埋め込む時だけです。」

ということです。

Comment: 同様のエラーを確認したところ、本家英語サイトの方はjsファイル内に＜script＞が入っていたみたいで、私のjsファイル内には＜script＞のような記述は無く、解決に至りませんでした。せっかく探してくださったのに申し訳ありません