# node,soket.io を利用したjavascriptのエラー

Tags: javascript, ios, html, iphone, socket

client.jsでエラーが起きているのですが、どこを直せばいいのかわかりません
`<`の記号でのエラーのようですけどどこにも使ってないのでさっぱりです
javascriptに詳しい方いらっしゃいましたらお願いいたします

エラー内容

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'　　　　client.js:1
```

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tomo-ono/20110530/1306740692
のサイトを参考に作成したのですが、解決方法が分かりません

上のURLを参考に作成したプロジェクトのソースコード

client.js

```
$(function() {
var socket = new io.Socket(null, {port: 8080});
socket.connect();

function iosHandleOrientation(event) {
    var orientData = event.accelerationIncludingGravity;
    socket.send(orientData.x + " " + orientData.y + " " + orientData.z );    
}

window.addEventListener("devicemotion", iosHandleOrientation, true);

socket.on('message', function(obj) {
    data = obj.split(" ");
    $('#data').append("<tr><td>" + parseFloat(data[0]).toFixed(3) + "</td><td>" + parseFloat(data[1]).toFixed(3) + "</td><td>" + parseFloat(data[2]).toFixed(3) + "</td></tr>");

});
});
```

server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http'),
    io = require('socket.io'),

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  fs.readFile('./socket.html','utf-8',doReard);
  function doReard(err,data){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
    res.end();
}
});
server.listen(8080);

var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('message', function(message) {
        client.broadcast(message);
        console.log(message);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('Conncection closed.');
    });
});
```

socket.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-   1.4.5.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="data">
<tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>z</th></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @seiyayamamoto スタック・オーバーフローは Q&A のデータベースとなることを目指しており、自分が過去にした質問をそのまま再投稿することは避けられています。なかなか問題が解決せずにお悩みのところ申し訳ありません。元の質問に対してコメントされている質問に答えることを優先してください。この際、コメントとして返答するのではなく、質問本文への追記として行ってください。更新された質問はより閲覧されるようになるので、回答が寄せられるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

`server.js`でリクエストのパスにかかわらず`socket.html`を返しているからではないでしょうか。

ブラウザは`<script src="client.js"></script>`というタグを見てサーバーに`/client.js`をリクエストしますが、返ってくるのはhtmlなのでそのようなエラーが出たのだと思います。

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) などを使うとルーティングが楽にできます。

関連リソース
[Express で静的ファイル（static ファイル）をホスティングする](https://maku77.github.io/nodejs/express/static-file.html)

Comment: 正しい回答だと思います。こちらが重複でクローズされたので、面倒だとは思いますが、https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40093/3054 の方へ同じ回答をいただくのがよいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。そちらにも投稿しておきます。